# "delete this" to an object that's allocated with std::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++11, shared-ptr

I know that it's possible to say `delete this` in C++ whenever you allocated something with `new`, using traditional pointers.  In fact, I also know that it's good practice IF you handle it carefully.  Can I have an object say `delete this` if it's being held by an `std::shared_ptr`?  And that ought to call the destructor, right?  To give you an idea, I'm making a game where a ship can shoot missiles, and I'd like to have the missiles delete themselves.

Comment: Having an object delete itself with `delete this` is _not_ good practice. The fact that you have to handle doing it carefully is enough to show that. It's an error prone way to arrange lifetime management.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it's not safe, the lifetime of the object is determined by holders of `shared_ptr`, so the object itself cannot decide whether it wants to die or not. If you do that, you'll get double 
delete when last `shared_ptr` dies. The only solution I can offer is "rethink your design" (you probably don't need `shared_ptr` in the first place, and missiles probably could be values or pooled objects).

Answer (score 3):

For a missile to delete itself it must own itself, or at the very least, share ownership of itself with others.  Since you say that there is a `shared_ptr` to the missile, I am assuming that you already have multiple objects sharing ownership of the missile.

It is possible for the missile to hold a `shared_ptr` to itself, and thus share in the ownership of itself.  However this will always create a cyclic ownership pattern:  For as long as the missile's shared_ptr data member refers to itself, the reference count can never drop to zero, and thus the missile is leaked.

You could have an external object or event tell the missile to delete itself but then I'm not sure what the point is.  In order to tell the missile to delete itself, that communication should take place via a `shared_ptr`, and then the delete isn't really going to happen until that `shared_ptr` lets go of the missile.

Yes, it is possible.  No, I don't think it is a good idea.  It looks prone to memory leakage to me and doesn't actually add value.  But for the curious, here is how you would do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class missile
    : public std::enable_shared_from_this<missile>
{
    std::shared_ptr<missile> self_;
public:
    missile()
      {} 

    ~missile() {std::cout << "~missile()\n";}

    void set_yourself()
    {
        self_ = shared_from_this();
    }
    void delete_yourself()
    {
        if (self_)
            self_.reset();
    }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        std::shared_ptr<missile> m = std::make_shared<missile>();
        m->set_yourself();
        std::weak_ptr<missile> wp = m;
        std::cout << "before first reset()\n";
        m.reset();
        std::cout << "after first reset()\n";
        // missile leaked here
        m = wp.lock();
        m->delete_yourself();
        std::cout << "before second reset()\n";
        m.reset();  // missile deleted here
        std::cout << "after second reset()\n";
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I should up vote.  The solution is correct and novel, but the question is wrong.

Comment: How is there a memory leak? The `wp` is not expired. You have exactly the same responsibility here as when dealing with raw pointers. With the bonus that you will not have the rug pulled out from under your feet if you happen to be using the missile while it deletes itself.

Comment: @EmilyL.:  I said *prone* to memory leak.  If something neglects to tell the missile to delete itself, then it leaks.  This example demonstrates that by removing all external owners without calling `delete_yourself`. The example then re-establishing an external owner, tells the missile to now delete itself, and then gets deleted when the external owner relinquishes ownership. I.e. why not just have external owners then?  A more common idiom is the for missile to only maintain a `weak_ptr` to itself, and hand out strong ownership to an external entity using that `weak_ptr`.

Comment: @deft_code:  My point was that it is possible, here's how, but this solution sucks.  It is error prone because it creates an ownership cycle that must be broken at run time, else there will be a leak.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the show but I ran into wanting to do this myself just now and realized that it is "kind-of-possible" but you need to take care of a few things.

Howard's answer is on the right track but misses the mark as you shouldn't leave construction of the original `shared_ptr` to the client. This is what opens up the risk of memory leaks. Instead you should encapsulate the construction and only allow weak pointers.

Here is an example:

```
class Missile{
private:
    Missile(...){ }; // No external construction allowed
    Missile(const Missile&) = delete; // Copying not allowed
    void operator = (const Missile&) = delete; // -||-

    std::shared_ptr<Missile> m_self;
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    static MissilePtr makeMissile(Args... args){ 
        auto that = std::make_shared<Misile>(args...);
        that.m_self = that; // that holds a reference to itself (ref count = 2)
        return that; // 'that' is destroyed and ref-count reaches 1.
    }

    void die(){
        m_self.reset();
    }

    ...
};

typedef std::weak_ptr<Missile> MissilePtr;

void useMissile(MissilePtr ptr){
    auto missile = ptr.lock(); // Now ptr cannot be deleted until missile goes out of scope
    missile->die(); // m_self looses the reference but 'missile' still holds a reference
    missile->whatever(); // Completely valid. Will not invoke UB
} // Exiting the scope will make the data in missile be deleted.
```

Calling `die()` will result in semantically the same effect as `delete this` with the added benefit that all `MissilePtr` that are referring to the deleted object will be expired. Also if any of the `MissilePtr` are used for accessing `this` then the deletion will be delayed until the temporary `std::shared_ptr` used for the access is destroyed saving you life-time headaches.

However you must make sure that you always keep at least one `MissilePtr` around and at some point call `die()` otherwise you will end up with a memory leak. Just like you would with a normal pointer.

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite old, but I had a similar issue (in this case a "listener" object that had to manage its own lifecycle while still being able to share weak pointers), and googling around did not provide a solution for me, so I am sharing the solution I found, assuming that:

- The object manages it's own lifecycle, and hence will never share a
  share_ptr, but a weak_ptr (if you need shared_ptr's a similar
  solution + use_shared_from_this could do it).
- It is a bad idea to break RAII, and hence we will not do it: what we
  adress here is the   issue of having a shared_ptr owned by an object
  itself, as containing a member share_ptr leads to double call to
  the object destruction and normally a crash (or at least undefined
  behaviour), as the destructor is called twice (once at normal
  object destruction and a second one when destroying the self
  contained shared_ptr member).

Code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <stdio.h>

using std::shared_ptr;
using std::weak_ptr;

class A {
    struct D {
            bool deleted = false;
            void operator()(A *p) {
                printf("[deleter (%s)]\n", p, deleted ? "ignored":"deleted");
                if(!deleted) delete p;
        }
    };

    public: shared_ptr<A> $ptr = shared_ptr<A>(this, D());

    public: ~A() {
        std::get_deleter<A::D>($ptr)->deleted = true;
    }

    public: weak_ptr<A> ptr() { return $ptr; }
};

void test() {
    A a;

    printf("count: %d\n", a.ptr().lock().use_count());
    printf("count: %d\n", a.ptr().use_count());
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    puts("+++ main");

    test();

    puts("--- main");
}
```

Output:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -o test test.cpp && ./test
+++ main
count: 2
count: 1
[deleter (ignored)]
--- main
```

The shared_ptr deleter should never get called for an object allocated in stack, so when it does at normal object destruction, it just bypasses the delete (we got to this point because the default object destructor was already called).